reproducing huggingface CLIP's output for the text encoder
i am trying to de-compose CLIP's text_model from huggingface but i'm running into some issues i don't understand.
In particular, as far as i understand calling CLIP.text_model should be the same as:

calculating the text embeddings with CLIP.text_model.embeddings
feeding the embeddings to CLIP.text_model.encoder
using CLIP.text_model.final_layer_norm

but when i try to compare the outputs i get different values for the two approaches.
here is my code so far:
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

model = CLIPModel.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-base-patch32")
model = model.to(device)
processor = CLIPProcessor.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-base-patch32")

def decomposed_text_model(text, processor, model, device):
    inputs = processor(text=text, return_tensors="pt", padding=True)
    attn_mask = inputs["attention_mask"].clone().detach().to(torch.bool).to(device)
    inputs = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in inputs.items()}
    
    embeddings = model.text_model.embeddings(inputs["input_ids"])
    position_embeddings=model.text_model.embeddings.position_embedding.weight[:inputs['input_ids'].shape[1]]
    embeddings = embeddings + position_embeddings.unsqueeze(0)
    encoder_output = model.text_model.encoder(
        inputs_embeds=embeddings, 
        attention_mask=attn_mask).last_hidden_state

    embeddings = model.text_model.final_layer_norm(encoder_output)

    return embeddings

def text_model(text, processor, model):
  inputs = processor(text="a photo of a cat", return_tensors="pt")
  inputs = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in inputs.items()}
  return model.text_model(**inputs)

# two step text approach
out1 = decomposed_text_model("a photo of a cat", processor, model)

out1 = out1.last_hidden_state[0, -1, :] # get eos token
out1 = out1.squeeze()

# one step text approach
out2 = text_model("a photo of a cat", processor, model)
out2 = out2.last_hidden_state[0, -1, :] # get eos token
out2 = out2.squeeze()

# compare
out1 = out1 / out1.norm(p = 2, dim=-1, keepdim=True)
out2 = out2 / out2.norm(p = 2, dim=-1, keepdim=True)

diff = torch.max(torch.abs(out1 - out2))
print(diff)

with diff being a somewhat high number (more fine-grained logging also revealed significant differences between the two eos tensors).
What am i missing? please understand that taking this approach is necessary to implement something, so i cannot just call text_model.
